# Path to select all images from a folder in the disk using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am loading all images from a folder from local disk and displaying using javascript.

I have given a button to open a local disk and choose files.

But I want to dynamically load images from a particular path on DOMready/onload instead of loading though a file select.

Here is link to what I have tried: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rrYxn/

Please please help.

Comment: Want to block the user to upload any file except image file... is this your motto?

Comment: How would you identify where the files are on the users disk. Also w3c guidelines specify that for security the user should select any files when using the File API. Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#security-discussion

Comment: No...I dont want to choose from button click. On page load, it should directly read from a local disk directory folder and load.

Comment: Probably I can get all the files from the given directory to an array?? But how...?

Comment: How would you know where the files are on the local disk ?

Comment: I can give the path something link this C://Users/.. know...?

Comment: Say for example - I am a user of ur website. How will your code know where the required images are on my local disk. Say you hardcode some path like C://Users/.. this type of structure for the file system exists only in Windows and not on Unix systems which means ur code will break if i open ur website in an Ubuntu Operating system. What exactly are you trying to achieve. I am pretty sure there will be some better way to implement it.

Comment: What about Webkitdirectory...?

Comment: Explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible to load file arbitrary from any users local disk.**

if possible , when you open Facebook.. it can upload all the photos in you computer with out asking you ans post it :). **so simply no.**

what you may need is to load some file from server (not local drive/path).

you can define th files to want to load like

```
var files = [
        'http://localhost/myproject/image1.png',
        'http://localhost/myproject/image2.png',
        'http://localhost/myproject/image3.png'
]
```

later the **localhost** will change to the domain name.

and use some script function to load these images

```
function loadImages(){
    for(var i=0; i< files .length; i++) {       
        var img = new Image();
            img.src = files[i];
        document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how to load from server. Should I use node.js? and write some server.js to create fs and run file.html that will actually do the above stuffs? I just heard it can be done by this. But don't know how. I installed node.js and created server.js in which I am creating http, fs and calling file.html.I wonder how to run this in cmd prompt. Kindly give me some clues.

Comment: it is advisable to read and understand the basic component of web development before you jump into actual development. like ..
`What is webserver ? difference in running a file from local path and through server ?`

`How webpages are hosted in server?'
`How can i run in localserver ?`
`What is back-end and frond-end components of web ?`